# Assign different values to a large number of columns

Tags: r

I have a large set of financial data that has hundreds of columns. I have cleaned and sorted the data based on date. Here is a simplified example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(vector(),ncol=5, nrow = 4))
colnames(df1) <- c("Date","0.4","0.3","0.2","0.1")
df1[1,] <- c("2000-01-31","0","0","0.05","0.07")
df1[2,] <- c("2000-02-29","0","0.13","0.17","0.09")
df1[3,] <- c("2000-03-31","0.03","0.09","0.21","0.01")
df1[4,] <- c("2004-04-30","0.05","0.03","0.19","0.03")
df1
        Date    0.4    0.3    0.2    0.1
1 2000-01-31      0      0   0.05   0.07
2 2000-02-29      0   0.13   0.17   0.09
3 2000-03-31   0.03   0.09   0.21   0.01
4 2000-04-30   0.05   0.03   0.19   0.03
```

I assigned individual weights (based on market value from the raw data) as column headers, because I don’t care about the company names and I need the weights for calculating the result.

My ultimate goal is to get: 1. Sum of the weighted returns; and 2. Sum of the weights when returns are non-zero. With that being said, below is the result I want to get:

```
        Date    SWeightedR    SWeights    
1 2000-01-31         0.017         0.3
2 2000-02-29         0.082         0.6
3 2000-03-31         0.082           1
4 2000-04-30          0.07           1
```

For instance, the SWeightedR for 2000-01-31 = 0.4x0+0.3x0+0.2x0.05+0.1x0.07, and SWeights = 0.2+0.1.

My initial idea was to assign the weights to each column like `WCol2 <- 0.4`, then use `cbind` to create new columns and use `c(as.matrix() %*% )` to get the sums. Soon I realize that this is impossible as there are hundreds of columns. Any advice or suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Are the values in the non-date columns numeric (`0.4`) or character (`"0.4"`) as per your example?

Comment: It's probably worth transforming from the wide `form` to a `long` form using the tidyr package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using matrix multiplications (as you were suggesting yourself).

First of all, your data seem to be of `character` type and I'm not sure it's the real case with the real data, but I would first convert it to an appropriate type

```
df1[-1] <- lapply(df1[-1], type.convert)
```

Next, we will convert the column names to a numeric class too

```
vec <- as.numeric(names(df1)[-1])
```

Finally, we could easily create the new columns in two simple steps. This indeed has a to matrix conversion overhead, but maybe you should work with matrices in the first place. Either way, this is fully vectorized

```
df1["SWeightedR"] <- as.matrix(df1[, -1]) %*% vec
df1["SWeights"] <- (df1[, -c(1, ncol(df1))] > 0) %*% vec
df1
#         Date  0.4  0.3  0.2  0.1 SWeightedR SWeights
# 1 2000-01-31 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.07      0.017      0.3
# 2 2000-02-29 0.00 0.13 0.17 0.09      0.082      0.6
# 3 2000-03-31 0.03 0.09 0.21 0.01      0.082      1.0
# 4 2004-04-30 0.05 0.03 0.19 0.03      0.070      1.0
```

Or, you could convert to a long format first (here's a `data.table` example), though I believe it will be less efficient as this are basically by row operations

```
library(data.table)
res <- melt(setDT(df1), id = 1L, variable.factor = FALSE
            )[, c("value", "variable") := .(as.numeric(value), as.numeric(variable))]
res[, .(SWeightedR = sum(variable * value),
        SWeights = sum(variable * (value > 0))), by = Date]

#          Date SWeightedR SWeights
# 1: 2000-01-31      0.017      0.3
# 2: 2000-02-29      0.082      0.6
# 3: 2000-03-31      0.082      1.0
# 4: 2004-04-30      0.070      1.0
```

Comment: Good option, plus one.

Comment: @David Arenburg my actual data turns out to be `factor` type. So when I apply `df1["SWeightedR"] <- as.matrix(df1[, -1]) %*% vec`, it will return the error `requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments`. I tried `df2 <- as.matrix(as.data.frame(lapply(df1[-1],as.numeric)))` to covert the data to numeric, but it meesed up my data (the returns became integers such as 1s and 2s). Please advise.

Comment: This is not how you convert a factor to numeric in R. Did you try Googling it? Try `df1[-1] <- lapply(df1[-1], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))` before doing any matrix multiplications.

Comment: Learning new things everyday. Thanks for your help Sir.